# Why does jQuery on click event set off click events bound in its callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#dropdown').on('click', function(){
    $(document).on('click', function(){
        console.log('Document event bound and fired');
    });
})
```

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wu85q/)

If the browser monitors for `mousedown` on the element and fires on `mouseup`, why on earth does the event bound to `document` fire, before it has been bound and before the browser has begun monitoring it for `mousedown` on it? What makes it weirder, is if you wrap the document on click binding in a 1 ms `setTimeout`, it completely negates this logical fallacy. Could someone explain to me what's going on here?

Comment: ***Never*** bind event handlers inside other event handlers, and certainly not event handlers bound to the document. The question is pretty much pointless, as the whole concept is flawed.

Comment: Just to answer the question, the event bubbles up to the document level.

Comment: It's just bubbling.  The click event will rise up the DOM through all parent elements and if any of them have a handler then it will fire.  This is *not* a logical fallacy.  This is a correlative-based fallacy.

Comment: The event bubbles from `#dropdown` up to `document`.  By the time the bubbling reaches `document` there is a handler there.

Comment: @adeneo if you use event.stopPropagation() and also unbind events appropriately, why should this be avoided?

Comment: @styke - Everytime you click the dropdown a new event handler is bound. You could of course unbind the event handler, then rebind it etc. but it's a lot easier and more efficient to just bind the event handler once, and then set a flag when the dropdown is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You press down on the mouse button over the element, and then lift up. A "click" event is generated.
2. The browser delivers the "click" to jQuery, which calls your outer handler.
3. Your handler assigns another handler for "click" events at the document level, and returns.
4. The browser now bubbles the event to your element's parent, and its parent, etc, until the document level is reached.
5. The "click" event now triggers the event handler you established at the document level.

Note that on the *second* click you trigger with your mouse, your document handler will be joined by a duplicate, so there'll be *two* console messages.